# SQLITE - NOT NULL Constraint Failed - transferring a row from one table to another

Tags: python, database, sqlite, debugging, flask

I'm building a to-do list API with sqlite and flask. I've got a main.py file, a todo.db, and a helper.py.

I have a function (which is my POST request). I have two database tables called incomplete and complete. My function is supposed to "complete" an action by deleting the corresponding task from incomplete, copying it, and putting it in complete.

I tried a lot of different things, kept getting different errors, from "database is locked" to "error binding parameter 1" and now this:

`Error:  NOT NULL constraint failed: complete.task`

I've gotten the function to at least delete the corresponding task from incomplete, and add something to complete, but it adds it incorrectly. Instead of something like this output when I use the GET request:

`[{"complete": [["678", "do dishes" ]]}, {"incomplete": [["756", "Setting up API"]]}]`

I get something like this

`[{"complete": [["678", "[]"]}, {"incomplete": [["756", "Setting up API"]]}]`

I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong. I'm also getting an error when I'm un-completing items (I get "Internal Server Error") :(

Here's the helper file, with parts ommitted. This snippet includes the relevant parts, and the part I'm focusing on is the add_to_completes().

```
import sqlite3
import random 

#for id's because users dont set them

DB_PATH = './todo.db'

# connect to database
conn = sqlite3.connect(DB_PATH)
c = conn.cursor()

c.execute("""CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS "complete" ("id" TEXT NOT NULL, "task" TEXT NOT NULL, PRIMARY KEY("id"));""")
# save the change
c.execute("""CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS "incomplete" ("id" TEXT NOT NULL, "task" TEXT NOT NULL, PRIMARY KEY("id"));""")
conn.commit()
def add_to_incomplete(task): 
    id = random.randint(100, 999)
    try:
        conn = sqlite3.connect(DB_PATH)
        c = conn.cursor()
        c.execute('insert into incomplete(id, task) values(?,?)', (id, task))
        conn.commit()
        return {"id": id}

    except Exception as e:
        print('Error: ', e)
        return None

def add_to_complete(inputId):
    try:
        conn = sqlite3.connect(DB_PATH)
        c = conn.cursor()
        c.execute('select task from incomplete where id=?', (inputId,))
        tasks = c.fetchone()
        c.execute('insert into complete values(?,?)', (inputId,tasks))
        delete_task(inputId)
        conn.commit()
        return {"id": id}

    except Exception as e:
        print('Error: ', e)
        return None

def get_all_completes():
    try: 
        conn = sqlite3.connect(DB_PATH)
        c = conn.cursor()
        c.execute('select * from complete')
        rows = c.fetchall()
        conn.commit()
        return { "complete": rows }
    except Exception as e:
        print('Error: ', e)
        return None

def get_all_incompletes():
    try:
        conn = sqlite3.connect(DB_PATH)
        c = conn.cursor()
        c.execute('select * from incomplete')
        rows = c.fetchall()
        conn.commit()
        return { "incomplete": rows } 
    except Exception as e:
        print('Error: ', e)
        return None 
def uncomplete(inputId):
    try:
        conn = sqlite3.connect(DB_PATH)
        c = conn.cursor()
        c.execute('select from complete where id=?', (inputId,))
        row = c.fetchall()
        c.execute('delete from complete where id=?', (inputId,))
        #you have that format (item,) because we need to pass execute() a tuple even if theres only one thing in the tuple
        add_to_incomplete(row)
        conn.commit()
        return {"id":id}
    except Exception as e:
        print('Error: ', e)
        return None
def delete_task(inputId):
    try:
        conn = sqlite3.connect(DB_PATH)
        c = conn.cursor()
        c.execute('delete from complete where id=?', (inputId,))
        c.execute('delete from incomplete where id=?', (inputId,))
        conn.commit()
        return {"id":id}
    except Exception as e:
        print('Error: ', e)
        return None
```

Here are the relevant parts of my main.py file:

```
import helper
from flask import Flask, request, Response

import json

app = Flask(__name__)

...

@app.route('/tasks/all', methods = ["GET"])
def get_all_items():
    res_data = helper.get_all_completes(), helper.get_all_incompletes()
    response = Response(json.dumps(res_data), mimetype='application/json')
    return response

@app.route('/tasks/complete', methods = ["POST"])
def complete_task():
    req_data = request.get_json()
    inputId = req_data['id']
    res_data = helper.add_to_complete(inputId)
    # find matching task to input id
    return "completed task" + inputId

@app.route('/tasks/incomplete', methods = ["PATCH"])
def uncomplete_task():
    req_data = request.get_json()
    inputId = req_data['id']
    res_data = helper.uncomplete(inputId)
    if res_Data is None:
        response =  Response("{'error': 'Error uncompleting task - '" + task + ", " + status   +  "}", status=400 , mimetype='application/json')
    response = Response(json.dumps(res_data), mimetype='application/json')
    return "uncompleted task" + " " + inputId 

...
@app.route('/tasks/remove', methods = ["DELETE"])
def delete():
    req_data = request.get_json()
    inputId = req_data['id']
    res_data = helper.delete_task(inputId)
    if res_data is None:
        response = Response("{'error': 'Error deleting task - '" + task +  "}", status=400 , mimetype='application/json')
    return "deleted task id" + " " + inputId
```

Comment: Please always share the entire error message. Be careful, `except Exception` is bad practice.

Comment: This `tasks = c.fetchone()` returns a sequence. So you probably want to do instead: `tasks = c.fetchone()[0]`.

Comment: I see! Thank you, that worked, now I have to fix the incomplete function :(

Comment: Fixed! Thanks :)